# Recurrence Relation Over Paths

Tags: graph-theory, recurrence-relations, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $v$ and $w$ be distinct vertices in $K_n$. Let $p_m$ denote the number of paths of length $m$ from $v$ to $w$ in $K_n$, $1\leq m \leq n$.

$(a)$ $\hspace{1cm}$Derive a recurrence relation for $p_m$.

$(b)$ $\hspace{1cm}$Find an explicit formula for $p_m$.

Comment: Excuse me? I believe you're the one asking question and your attitude is clearly not very ... positive here.  If you want to get help then some us some respect and put your work down, this is not Chegg or CourseHero!

Comment: @Danny: You’re also asking a question, and you’re asking it of a newcomer with no explanation of why you’re asking it. You’re also one of the most viciously quick closers on the site. That’s not a very ... positive attitude.

Comment: Alright, I'll change that attitude of mine, you're right ... apologies

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Clearly $p_1=1$: there’s only one path of length $1$ from $v$ to $w$. A path of length $2$ from $v$ to $w$ must consist of an edge from $v$ to some vertex $u$ other than $w$ followed by the edge from $u$ to $w$, so there is one of these paths for each vertex $u$ that isn’t $v$ or $w$. There are $n-2$ such edges, so $p_2=n-2$. What about paths of length $3$ from $v$ to $w$? Such a path can be broken into a path of length $2$ from $v$ to some vertex $u\ne w$ followed by the edge from $u$ to $w$. Moreover, $u\ne v$, so there are $n-2$ possible choices for $u$. (I’m assuming here that your definition of *path* does not allow repeated vertices.) If there are $n-2$ choices for $u$, and $p_2$ paths of length $2$ from $v$ to each of these possible vertices $u$, what is $p_3$?

If you can answer that last question, you should be able to generalize the idea just a little to get the desired recurrence, and once you have the right recurrence, getting the closed form is pretty easy.

Comment: $p_3=n-3$, yes?

Comment: @Loie: No, it’s much larger than that. There are $p_2$ paths of length $2$ from $v$ to each of $n-2$ different intermediate vertices $u$, so a path of length $3$ from $v$ to $w$ can be built in $p_2(n-2)$ ways. This is just the basic [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) of counting. What is $p_2(n-2)$ just in terms of $n$?

Comment: $p_3=(n-2)^2$, yes?

Comment: Is the explicit formula $p_m=(n-2)^{m-1}$?

Comment: $p_m= (n−1)_{m−1}−p_{m−1}$, yes?

Comment: @Trancot: It’s just $p_m=(n-2)p_{m-1}$, with $p_1=1$, and therefore $p_m=(n-2)^{m-1}$, as you suggest.